# MySQL Trigger update after an insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

What is the right syntax for an update after an insert on a sql trigger?

I am trying:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER movimentacoes AFTER INSERT ON
    mov FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        cooperados
    INNER JOIN mov ON mov.id_coop = cooperados.id
    SET
        cooperados.integralizadas = cooperados.integralizadas + mov.valor
    WHERE
        mov.id_coop = cooperados.id
```

I'm building an application with laravel, and this trigger is essential.

Comment: Hard to help you with no information about what you want to update and the table structure where the trigger is created. But with your example you have no "END" and no `NEW.value` to use the inserted value.

Comment: The correct syntax would be to have an end to match the begin and for your update statement to be terminated. But I would expect to see reference to NEW. value(s).Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE TRIGGER movimentacoes AFTER INSERT ON mov
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE cooperados c
        SET integralizadas = c.integralizadas + new.valor
    WHERE c.id = new.id_coop;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```